# How to get absolute value from double - c-language

Tags: c, double

I want the absolute-value from a negative double - and I thought the `abs`-function was as easy to use as in java - but NOT!

It seems that the `abs`-function returns an int because I have the value 3.8951 and the output is 3.000000

```
double d1 = abs(-3.8951);
printf("d1: ...%lf", d1);
```

How can I fix this problem? That is - I want the absolute value of a `double`.

Comment: Did you try `fabs(-3.8951)`? `man abs` says "compute the absolute value of an integer" and `fabs(3)` is cross-referenced in the "SEE ALSO". Never assume that things work the same way across different languages. Especially since Java has classes and can overload methods, but C does not.

Comment: @mbratch - thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I will consider this in the future

Comment: abs is only implemented for integer in C. That's why the answers are all recommending you use fabs, which is the floating-point equivalent.

Comment: " absolute-value from a negative double" is easy: `-x`. ;-)

Comment: If this question was asked in 2023, it could possibly get -15 downvotes + duplicate + close. :P

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use [**`fabs()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs) (in <kbd>math.h</kbd>) to get absolute-value for `double`:

```
double d1 = fabs(-3.8951);
```

Comment: As you where slighty faster than haccks you won.

Comment: fabs() is for doubles. fabsf() is for floats.

Comment: Both of them deserve my love equally.

Answer (score 23):

Use `fabs` instead of `abs` to find absolute value of `double` (or `float`) data types. Include the `<math.h>` header for `fabs` function.

```
double d1 = fabs(-3.8951);
```

Answer (score 5):

It's worth noting that Java can overload a method such as `abs` so that it works with an integer or a double. In C, overloading doesn't exist, so you need different functions for integer versus double.

Comment: "In C, overloading doesn't exist" -->  Disagree in part, research `<tgmath.h>` to use `fabs()` with various FP types.  Similar effect possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using `cabs(double)`, `cabsf(float)`, `cabsl(long double)`, `__cabsf(float)`, `__cabs(double)`, `__cabsf(long double)` is the solution

Comment: These `cabs`-like functions are for complex numbers, so it may be out of scope of this question. It would be good to [edit] your post and include this information (and maybe explain what's the difference between `cabs` and `__cabs`)

Answer (score 0):

```
  //use fabs()
  double sum_primary_diagonal=0;
  double sum_secondary_diagonal=0;
  double difference = fabs(sum_primary_diagonal - sum_secondary_diagonal);
```